# Find minimum number and set property to a value

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list of Item objects that have properties

```
- DateValue
- IsMin
```

How can I look through a list and set IsMin=true where the DateValue is the minimum date value in the list?

Comment: Something like: `YourList.OrderBy(Function(item) item.DataValue).First.IsMin = true`

Comment: @DanielCook: This looks like a good answer actually. You should post it below.

Comment: Could there be more than one object with the same minumum DateValue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

`YourList.OrderBy(Function(item) item.DataValue).First.IsMin = true`

OrderBy sorts by DataValue

First returns the first element

Then IsMin = true sets IsMin to true...

Comment: +1. I like your option better - it combines min and index operation in one. So your `First` = my `Min` + `v(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Class MyItem
  Public Property DateValue As DateTime
  Public Property IsMin As Boolean
End Class

Sub Main()
  Dim lst As New List(Of MyItem)
  lst.Add(New MyItem With {.DateValue = Today})
  lst.Add(New MyItem With {.DateValue = Today.AddDays(-1)})
  lst.Add(New MyItem With {.DateValue = Today.AddDays(1)})

  Dim v = From itm As MyItem In lst
          Where itm.DateValue = lst.Min(Function(x) x.DateValue)

  v(0).IsMin = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, I thought about offering that suggestion. Nice set up code since the OP didn't provide any. ;-)